# Efficient ways of randomizing treatments in oTree

Tags: python, django, otree

I am writing the code for the experiment I am going to run in my master thesis. I am basically done, but I am stuck with one last aspect I cannot find the way to solve. I have a public good game with 16 participants, divided in 8 two-players groups. I have 4 treatments and I balanced the game, s.t. every treatment is played by 4 players each round (they are 12). The part I am missing at the moment is that I would like that every player does play every round exactly 3 times. This randomization is executed in the code below, which theoretically works, but practically I never managed to get to the end of it. in 20 minutes I managed to get at the end of Round 10, but could not make the program find a combination that satisfies the two conditions above for round 11 and 12. I know it is a bit tricky and it is easier to understand if you are into it, but... do you have any suggestions? 
Thanks a lot!

```
class Subsession(BaseSubsession):

    def before_session_starts(self):
        info_condition = ['Bel', 'Bel', 'Act', 'Act', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'No', 'No']
        i = 0
        condition = True
        while condition:
            i+= 1
            print('I am in the loop: {} th time. Round{}.'.format(i, self.round_number))
            self.group_randomly()
            for gr_index, g in enumerate(self.get_groups()):
                g.info = info_condition[gr_index]
                for p in g.get_players():
                    p.info_player = g.info

            condition = any(not p.can_go_on(p.info_player) for p in self.get_players())
            if condition == False:
                break
        p.count_treat()
        print('I am out of the loop. Round{}'.format(self.round_number))

class Player(BasePlayer):

    runs = models.CharField()

    def count_treat(self):
        ctrl_count = 0
        no_count = 0
        bel_count = 0
        act_count = 0
        for p in self.in_all_rounds():
            if p.info_player == "Ctrl":
                ctrl_count += 1
            elif p.info_player == "No":
                no_count += 1
            elif p.info_player == "Bel":
                bel_count += 1
            elif p.info_player == "Act":
                act_count += 1
            p.runs = dict()
            p.runs['Ctrl'] = ctrl_count
            p.runs['Bel'] = bel_count
            p.runs['No'] = no_count
            p.runs['Act'] = act_count


    def can_go_on(self, activity):
        self.count_treat()
        print(self.id_in_subsession, self.runs[activity] < 4, activity, self.runs[activity])
        return self.runs[activity] < 4
```

Comment: does it mean that each player plays three rounds of 'Bel' treatment, then three rounds of 'Act' treatment etc.?

Comment: Yes, but possibly in a random fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to add another answer instead of editing previous one, because the first one can still be helpful in case you don't need to reshuffle groups.

So, let's say you have four treatments - [A, B, C, D]

There are three conditions:

1. *Condition 1*: A player plays a random treatment from this set for three rounds, and then plays a next (random) treatment for three rounds etc.

   We can depict a sequence for a particular player as a list: AAABBBCCCDDD, where a letter corresponds to a treatment and its position in this string corresponds to a round number.
2. *Condition 2*: In each round there are exactly four players who play the same treatment.
3. *Condition 3*: reshuffling. Which means that there are no players at all who have exactly the same treatment sequence across all rounds. So if someone played AAABBBCCCDDD, no one can do the same, and to be one of those four players of A in first three rounds, another player needs to have something like AAABBBDDDCCC.

Since people play always three rounds in a row (like AAA, or BBB), let's depict a triplet AAA as **A**, etc - just for the sake of brevity. So AAABBBCCCDDD would be **ABCD**.

The code below produces a matrix 12X16, where every player plays each treatment three times in a row and which satisfies all the 3 conditions.

**The code is FAR from optimal**, and I believe that more experienced python programmers will easily do it **a way** more efficient. But it works. All you need to do is just assign this matrix to any `session.vars` variable and then each player can obtain his/her treatment based on his id and round number.

function `by_letters` compares two sequences and return `True` if there is at least one letter at the same position in both sequences. So it returns `True` for `abcd` and `bdca` because of the `c`, but it returns `False` for `abcd` and `badc`.

we generate at the beginning all (24) possible permutations of our four treatments. That is a pool of sequences we can use.

The function `filtered` returns a subset of the available sequences which do not have the coinciding letters (based on `by_letters` function).

The function `triple` just repeats each treatment three times, when the matrix of treatment is found.

So we get the initial data by producing permutations from our set of treatments.

We pick a random sequence from it, and then we filter out the remaining data based on this first draw. That's our second sequence.

We find an intersection of two sets, which both do not have coinciding letters with both sequence 1 and sequence 2. Then from the remaining subset we drew a random line. That's our third sequence.

We do the same intersection of three sets to pick up a fourth sequence.
That's our first matrix of 4X4. 
We filter out all our sequences from initial data (by using `itertools.filterfalse`), and we loop four times using an initial data but without our sequences which we just found.

Since not every time it is possible to find 4 matrices of 4X4 which satisfies all the conditions, we use `try.. except..` to draw another random starting sequence.

```
import random
import itertools
initial_data = list(itertools.permutations('abcd'))

def by_letters(a, b):
    u = zip(a, b)
    for i, j in u:
        if i == j:
            return True
    return False


def filtered(what):
    x = [i for i in a if not by_letters(i, what)]
    return x


def triple(str):
    return ''.join([c+c+c for c in str])

result = None

while result is None:
    try:
        matrices = []
        a = initial_data
        for i in range(4):
            print('cycle:: ', i)
            line1 = random.choice(a)
            line2 = random.choice(filtered(line1))
            s1 = set(filtered(line1))
            s2 = set(filtered(line2))
            sets = [s1, s2]
            line3 = random.choice(list(set.intersection(*sets)))
            s3 = set(filtered(line3))
            sets = [s1, s2, s3]
            line4 = random.choice(list(set.intersection(*sets)))
            matrix1 = [line1, line2, line3, line4]
            matrices.append(matrix1)
            a = list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x in matrix1, a))
        result = matrices                

    except IndexError:
         pass

final = [triple(j) for i in matrices for j in i]
print(final)
```

and output is something like:

```
...
['aaabbbdddccc', 'dddcccaaabbb', 'cccdddbbbaaa', 'bbbaaacccddd', 
'cccdddaaabbb', 'aaabbbcccddd', 'bbbaaadddccc', 'dddcccbbbaaa', 
'aaacccbbbddd', 'dddaaacccbbb', 'cccbbbdddaaa', 'bbbdddaaaccc', 
'dddaaabbbccc', 'bbbdddcccaaa', 'aaacccdddbbb', 'cccbbbaaaddd']
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems great. I mean, it's not the solution where I randomize everything every single time, but I am quite confident this will not affect my results. I managed to assign the treatment to the players, now I need to create the groups out of it! I guess that by using the set_group_matrix method somehow I should be fine!

Comment: Hi Philipp. One last question (you'll definitely be in the "Thanks" page of my thesis). I cannot post the code here (too long), but I grouped all players in each round that have the same treatment and created a list of lists, as in the documentation, using the append command. Then `self.in_round(i).set_group_matrix(self.in_round(i).matrix)` and I get  'The group matrix must contain each player ' ValueError: The group matrix must contain each player in the subsession exactly once. I checked the type and it's public_goods.models.Player and all the players are there. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: hi Denis,
Do you think you can share the code in github? If you don't want to share the entire repository, you can use gist.github to insert some pieces of code which are too long to share in SO comments

Comment: PS: The app I'm working on at the moment is the "public good" one

Comment: I'll have a look now

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I got the problem, but if I suggest that the task is to randomize the order of treatments in within-subjects design, so each player would play each treatment for three times, but this order should be randomized across players. Then I think it can be done like that:

in `models.py`:

```
import random
class Constants(BaseConstants):
      treatments = [['Bel', 'Bel','Bel'],
             ['Act', 'Act', 'Act'],
             ['Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl'],
             ['No', 'No', 'No']]

class Subsession(BaseSubsession):
def before_session_starts(self):
    if not self.session.vars.get('treatments'):
        treatments = []
        for g in self.get_groups():
            group_treatments = Constants.treatments
            random.shuffle(group_treatments)
            flat_treatments = [item for sublist in group_treatments for item in sublist]
            if g.id % 2 != 0:
                treatments.append(flat_treatments)
            else:
                treatments.append(treatments[-1])
        self.session.vars['treatments'] = treatments

    for g in self.get_groups():
        g.treatment = self.session.vars['treatments'][g.id - 1][g.round_number - 1]
```

What do we do here?
In `Constants` we create a list of lists with sets of treatments (not the most elegant way, so if you need to vary the length of rounds, do it in more python way, but for the sake of laziness it works).

Then when each `Subsession` is initiated you obtain this list of lists, for each group we shuffle them (the items inside each sublists are not shuffled then), and then make them flat, so it is just a list.After that we add this shuffled list of treatments to a list (of lists) at the session level.

So after the first round in `treatments` session variable you have a complete array of all treatments for each group.

And then you just set `treatment` model field in `Group` model equal to the item from list of individualized treatments, corresponding to the current round and group id.

UPDATED: to make treatment sequences the same for two groups

Comment: Hi! 
Thanks for the help for starters, but I'm not sure this works. I see your logic here, however I also need that in each round each treatment is assigned to two groups (or four players). And this is not present in here.

Comment: you can do this for odd groups only, and copy the treatment sequences to even ones:

Comment: Mmm. I see what you are doing here, but as I understood it you want to keep the groups fixed over the rounds, right? I need the groups to be shuffled and I think that with your code is likely I get that one player will not satisfy the condition of facing the same treatment not more than three times. IF i got your code right...

Comment: Ps: I might have found a solution. In the meantime thanks for changing a bit the perspective on which I was too focused. I would lose a bit in terms of randomization with this solution but is better than nothing. I'll post this later in the afternoon if I manage to programm it...